# How do you cause com.actionbarsherlock to be in the gen folder of an Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, actionbarsherlock, r.java-file

I'm trying to build and run the demos included with ActionBarSherlock. I go to File -> New Android project from existing source, and navigate to the samples/demos directory. The project is imported into eclipse, however, none of the R. references are resolved, because com.actionbarsherlock doesn't appear in the gen folder.

The actionbarsherlock library *is* being referenced (Properties -> Android -> Libraries). actionbarsherlock.jar *is* in the Android Dependencies folder.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Just referencing the library in another eclipse project causes com.actionbarsherlock to be properly generated. I have no idea why the same behavior in this demos project isn't generating com.actionbarsherlock.R.

EDIT 2: And now it has magically decided to work. I did nothing special, just continually referenced and un-referenced the library until it worked.

**Thanks for looking all, the problem's been solved**

Comment: You should delete the question if it is no longer relevant (since you answered yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the gen folder (and R.java) are generated during compilation.  Try doing a clean and build to see if R and gen/ get created.

If they don't, then compilation is failing.  If there are any errors in eclipse that are *not* related to missing R.java, fix them or post them as a comment for more info.

This might be a problem with the `import my.project.R` statements at the top of each java file, but checking the errors will confirm or deny this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the gen folder is created until you try to run the app.

If this isn't the issue, you could try fixing the project properties. `Right click on the project --> Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties`